# WSO2 API Manager Sequences are getting overidded with initial version

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I had created Message Mediation policy on an API published in WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0.  Due to new requirements, I modified the policy in the /synapse/default/sequences/API-Name.xml .It works as expected but it gets reverted to the initial version when wso2am is restarted. 
I am facing issue using the WSO2 Plugin with eclipse and hence updating the sequence in this manner. Is this the right way to update or Is there any other change i am missing?

Comment: Are you following the approach of uploading the sequence for an API via publisher UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the file is getting replaced with the value in the registry. This looks like a bug.

As a workaround, you can edit sequence saved in the registry.

1. Navigate to carbon console.
2. Home->Resources->Browse.
3. Go to path /_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in/
4. Edit as xml.
5. Save and restart.

[image]